# How to create a non-rectangular button with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, button, vcl

How to create a transparent non-rectangular button with Delphi?

Comment: If it's really so urgent, you shouldn't be trying to create it yourself. It will take you too long just to figure out the basics. You're better off finding one of the dozens of already-made non-rectangular buttons. Try Torry's.

Answer (score 5):

Basically you use [SetWindowRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145102%28VS.85%29.aspx) to define the shape of your button/control/window. See [here](http://delphiptt.blogspot.com/2007/06/rounded-buttons-with-bitmaps-for-updown.html) for an example.

Or if you don't mind that your button can't be selected by the keyboard you could also use a TImage and use the OnMouseUp event.

Or find a 3rd party button that already does what you want on [Torry](http://www.torry.ru/pages.php?id=80).

Answer (score 2):

You could use SetWindowRgn only if you didn't mind it looking quite odd - the bits that fall outside the region will simply be gone. Your best bet is probably deriving from TCustomTransparentControl, but you'd then need to do custom painting. I suspect though, that custom painting was what you expected all along?

Answer (score 1):

[Raize Components](http://www.raize.com/DevTools/RzComps/ComponentList.asp) has a component called TRzShapeButton, but there are probably free alternatives too.

Comment: +1 - And you get so many other components which are very mature and come with fantastic support.  A very well thought out library.